# ngb modal appearing under backdrop

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I've seen this question asked in a few places but they all seem to be saying "don't put the modal or the backdrop in a parent that has a position property set" but my modal and backdrop are both under the `body` element with no other parent, here's a screenshot of the element stack:

[image]

when I observe the modal backdrop it has a `z-index: 1040` and the `ngb-modal-window` has `z-index: 50`. When i change those numbers so that the window has a higher `z-index` than the backdrop, the problem is fixed, but why is it doing that to begin with?

I've also looked through our app css and we're not overriding any of the css rules. Is it a versioning issue? `package.json` says `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.3.0",`